# No known workingObject when trying to enable multi-threading in Optaplanner

Tags: optaplanner

I'm trying to enable multi-threading for my Optaplanner setup. The documentation states that, in doing so, one should annotate each planning entity and planning value class with `@PlanningId` on a field or getter serving as a unique ID.

Below, as a planning value class.

```
public class TimeSlot {

@PlanningId
private String id; //Unique for each instance, and initialized in constructor

...
}
```

And, multi-threading is enabled in a properties file.

```
optaplanner.solver.move-thread-count=AUTO
```

When I run my code, I get the following exception.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The move thread with moveThreadIndex (0) has thrown an exception. Relayed here in the parent thread.
at org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.thread.OrderByMoveIndexBlockingQueue.take(OrderByMoveIndexBlockingQueue.java:147)
at org.optaplanner.core.impl.constructionheuristic.decider.MultiThreadedConstructionHeuristicDecider.forageResult(MultiThreadedConstructionHeuristicDecider.java:186)
at org.optaplanner.core.impl.constructionheuristic.decider.MultiThreadedConstructionHeuristicDecider.decideNextStep(MultiThreadedConstructionHeuristicDecider.java:157)
at org.optaplanner.core.impl.constructionheuristic.DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase.solve(DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase.java:75)
at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.AbstractSolver.runPhases(AbstractSolver.java:99)
at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver.solve(DefaultSolver.java:189)
at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolverJob.call(DefaultSolverJob.java:101)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:264)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The externalObject ({ TimeSlot: {begin:"2021-08-01T00:30:00", end:"2021-08-01T02:15:00"} }) with planningId ((class com.timetime.assistedengine.domain.TimeSlot,549290301)) has no known workingObject (null).
Maybe the workingObject was never added because the planning solution doesn't have a @ProblemFactCollectionProperty annotation on a member with instances of the externalObject's class (class com.timetime.assistedengine.domain.TimeSlot).
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.lookup.PlanningIdLookUpStrategy.lookUpWorkingObject(PlanningIdLookUpStrategy.java:66)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.lookup.LookUpManager.lookUpWorkingObject(LookUpManager.java:76)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.AbstractScoreDirector.lookUpWorkingObject(AbstractScoreDirector.java:512)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.selector.move.generic.ChangeMove.rebase(ChangeMove.java:83)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.selector.move.generic.ChangeMove.rebase(ChangeMove.java:31)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.move.CompositeMove.rebase(CompositeMove.java:125)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.move.CompositeMove.rebase(CompositeMove.java:38)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.thread.MoveThreadRunner.run(MoveThreadRunner.java:140)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    ... 5 more
```

The problem seems to be that no workingObject (an internal Optaplanner concept I presume) could not be found for instances of the `TimeSlot` class.

When digging in the Optaplanner source code through the stack trace, it seemed to be the case that Optaplanner internally could only have knowledge of a `workingObject` if the corresponding value range of the class that corresponds the `workingObject` has a `@ProblemFactProperty` or a `@ProblemFactCollectionProperty` on it.

In my case, the value range is on the Planning Entity, and not the Planning Solution. The value range is thus different for each Planning Entity instance. I'm not sure if this is a hindrance, because labeling the value range with the above annotation (`@ProblemFactCollectionProperty`) doesn't help.

Other then the `TimeSlot` class, I have another planning value class (also with a value range on the planning entity), and a single problem fact instance on the Planning Solution. They, and the Planning Entities themselves, all have ID's annotated with `@PlanningId`.

Comment: That `planningId ((class com.timetime.assistedengine.domain.TimeSlot,549290301))` seems weird if it's a String as you mentioned above it.

Comment: Oh, I changed it before this post and forgot about it. Posted in the stack trace is the hash code of the objects, serving as `@PlanningId`, but I also generated IDs with `ObjectId.get().toString()`, which is what the text in my post would represent. 

Both generated the same exception above. @GeoffreyDeSmet

Answer (score 0):

Got this working by adding @ProblemFactCollectionProperty to List attribute of class decorated with @PlanningSolution and adding @ProblemFactCollectionProperty, @ValueRangeProvider to List attribute of class decorated with @PlanningEntity. So actual value range returned for each @PlanningEntity object and all values returned for @PlanningSolution object.

For example:

```
@PlanningSolution
public class Schedule {
    // no ValueRangeProvider!
    @ProblemFactCollectionProperty
    private List<Timeslot> timeslots;
}

@PlanningEntity
public class Meeting {
    @ProblemFactCollectionProperty
    @ValueRangeProvider(id = "timeslotRange")
    private List<Timeslot> suitableTimeslots;
}
```