# Optaplanner multithreading exception: "The externalObject ... has no known workingObject"

Tags: java, multithreading, kotlin, optimization, optaplanner

**TLDR**: Enabling multithreading in Optaplanner is supposed to be a one-liner, but it throws an exception

I'm trying to optimize a damage calculation using configurable loadouts in a videogame. For context, a player may configure each item they own with a "reforge," which adds stats for strength or crit damage. The final damage calculation must be maximized as a combination of strength and crit damage. For this reason, I am using Optaplanner to allocate reforges to items.

However, enabling multithreading through `<moveThreadCount>AUTO</moveThreadCount>` in the XML solver config throws an exception (that does not occur in single-threaded execution):

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The externalObject (ReforgeProblemFact(id=897f4bab-80e0-4eb9-a1d7-974f7cddfd9e, name=Fierce, rarity=COMMON, strength=4, critDamage=0)) with planningId ((class net.javaman.optaplanner_reproducible.ReforgeProblemFact,897f4bab-80e0-4eb9-a1d7-974f7cddfd9e)) has no known workingObject (null).
Maybe the workingObject was never added because the planning solution doesn't have a @ProblemFactCollectionProperty annotation on a member with instances of the externalObject's class (class net.javaman.optaplanner_reproducible.ReforgeProblemFact).
```

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66754103/no-known-workingobject-when-trying-to-enable-multi-threading-in-optaplanner) is similar, but its answer doesn't fix the exception in this example.

I removed packages and imports in the code below. [Full GitHub repository link](https://github.com/TheNewJavaman/optaplanner-reproducible)

Project structure:

```
src/main/
    kotlin/
        net/javaman/optaplanner_reproducible/
            Rarity.kt
            ReforgeProblemFact.kt        
            ItemPlanningEntity.kt
            ReforgePlanningSolution.kt
            MaximizeDamageConstraintProvider.kt
            Main.kt
    resources/
        reforgeSolverConfig.xml
```

Rarity.kt:

```kotlin
enum class Rarity {
    COMMON,
    RARE,
    LEGENDARY
}
```

ReforgeProblemFact.kt:

```kotlin
data class ReforgeProblemFact(
    @PlanningId
    val id: UUID,
    val name: String,
    val rarity: Rarity,
    val strength: Int,
    val critDamage: Int
)
```

ItemPlanningEntity.kt:

```kotlin
@PlanningEntity
data class ItemPlanningEntity @JvmOverloads constructor(
    @PlanningId
    val id: UUID? = null,
    val rarity: Rarity? = null,
    @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = ["reforgeRange"])
    var reforge: ReforgeProblemFact? = null,
    @ValueRangeProvider(id = "reforgeRange")
    @ProblemFactCollectionProperty
    val availableReforges: List<ReforgeProblemFact>? = null
)
```

ReforgePlanningSolution.kt:

```kotlin
@PlanningSolution
class ReforgePlanningSolution @JvmOverloads constructor(
    @PlanningEntityCollectionProperty
    val availableItems: List<ItemPlanningEntity>? = null,
    @PlanningScore
    val score: HardSoftScore? = null,
)
```

MaximizeDamageConstraintProvider.kt:

```kotlin
class MaximizeDamageConstraintProvider : ConstraintProvider {
    override fun defineConstraints(factory: ConstraintFactory): Array<Constraint> = arrayOf(maximizeDamage(factory))

    // This approach does not take full advantage of incremental solving,
    // but it is necessary to compute strength and critDamage together in the same equation
    private fun maximizeDamage(factory: ConstraintFactory) = factory.from(ItemPlanningEntity::class.java)
        .map(ItemPlanningEntity::reforge) // Get each item's reforge
        .groupBy({ 0 }, toList { reforge: ReforgeProblemFact? -> reforge }) // Compile into one List<ReforgeProblemFact>
        .reward("damage", HardSoftScore.ONE_SOFT) { _, reforges: List<ReforgeProblemFact?> ->
            val strengthSum = reforges.stream().collect(Collectors.summingInt { reforge -> reforge?.strength ?: 0 })
            val critDamageSum = reforges.stream().collect(Collectors.summingInt { reforge -> reforge?.critDamage ?: 0 })
            (100 + strengthSum) * (100 + critDamageSum)
        }
}
```

Main.kt:

```kotlin
class Main {
    companion object {
        private val allReforges = listOf(
            ReforgeProblemFact(UUID.randomUUID(), "Clean", Rarity.COMMON, 0, 3),
            ReforgeProblemFact(UUID.randomUUID(), "Fierce", Rarity.COMMON, 4, 0),
            ReforgeProblemFact(UUID.randomUUID(), "Shiny", Rarity.COMMON, 2, 1),
            ReforgeProblemFact(UUID.randomUUID(), "Clean", Rarity.RARE, 1, 3),
            ReforgeProblemFact(UUID.randomUUID(), "Fierce", Rarity.RARE, 5, 0),
            ReforgeProblemFact(UUID.randomUUID(), "Shiny", Rarity.RARE, 3, 2),
            ReforgeProblemFact(UUID.randomUUID(), "Clean", Rarity.LEGENDARY, 1, 4),
            ReforgeProblemFact(UUID.randomUUID(), "Fierce", Rarity.LEGENDARY, 6, 0),
            ReforgeProblemFact(UUID.randomUUID(), "Shiny", Rarity.LEGENDARY, 4, 2),
        )
        private val solverManager: SolverManager<ReforgePlanningSolution, UUID> = SolverManager.create(
            SolverConfig.createFromXmlResource("reforgeSolverConfig.xml")
        )

        @JvmStatic
        fun main(args: Array<String>) {
            val availableItems = generateAvailableItems(
                mapOf(
                    Rarity.COMMON to 4,
                    Rarity.RARE to 3,
                    Rarity.LEGENDARY to 1
                )
            )
            val solverJob = solverManager.solve(UUID.randomUUID(), ReforgePlanningSolution(availableItems))
            val solution = solverJob.finalBestSolution
            solution.availableItems!!
                .map { it.reforge!! }
                .forEach { println(it.rarity.name + " " + it.name) }
        }

        private fun generateAvailableItems(itemCounts: Map<Rarity, Int>): MutableList<ItemPlanningEntity> {
            val availableItems = mutableListOf<ItemPlanningEntity>()
            for (itemCount in itemCounts) {
                for (count in 0 until itemCount.value) {
                    val rarity = itemCount.key
                    availableItems.add(
                        ItemPlanningEntity(
                            UUID.randomUUID(),
                            rarity,
                            null,
                            allReforges.filter { it.rarity == rarity }
                        )
                    )
                }
            }
            return availableItems
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool, which video game is this?

Comment: What happens if you turn on `FULL_ASSERT`? Maybe the input modes uses values that aren't in the value range.

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet This tool is for Hypixel SkyBlock, a Minecraft server. For more info, look up SkyBlockSimplified, which I'm helping rewrite. `FULL_ASSERT` doesn't change the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I revisited [the similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66754103/no-known-workingobject-when-trying-to-enable-multi-threading-in-optaplanner). After trying a few different versions of the answer, it finally worked. Here's a more detailed explanation than the other post:

Each `PlanningEntity`'s `ProblemFactCollectionProperty` must be part of the main `ProblemFactCollectionProperty` in the `PlanningSolution`. This means that both the entity and solution should have their problem facts defined. Here's what fixed it for me:

Keep ItemPlanningEntity.kt the same.

Include a global `ProblemFactCollectionProperty` in ReforgePlanningSolution.kt:

```kotlin
@PlanningSolution
class ReforgePlanningSolution @JvmOverloads constructor(
    @PlanningEntityCollectionProperty
    val availableItems: List<ItemPlanningEntity>? = null,
    @ProblemFactCollectionProperty
    val allReforges: List<ReforgeProblemFact>? = null,
    @PlanningScore
    val score: HardSoftScore? = null
)
```

Define the global collection when instantiating the solution in Main.kt:

```kotlin
val solverJob = solverManager.solve(UUID.randomUUID(), ReforgePlanningSolution(availableItems, allReforges))
```

Comment: The error message should point this out in a "Maybe" line. We'll fix that.

Comment: It was already fixed in Januari 2019, please upgrade OptaPlanner to get the correct error message.

Answer (score 0):

> The externalObject (ReforgeProblemFact(id=897f...)) with planningId ((class ReforgeProblemFact,897f...)) has no known workingObject (null).

That `planningId ((class ReforgeProblemFact` makes no sense, as the planningId class is UUID in your model.
Looking at the code of `PlanningIdLookUpStrategy` line 71, the error message is correct. Put a breakpoint on that line and look at what kind of class the planningId variable is. It should be a UUID.

Comment: `extractPlanningId` returns an `ImmutablePair` of `"class net.javaman.optaplanner_reproducible.ReforgeProblemFact" -> "04bb4456-4fc5-4a1b-bdb7-7bc570da5142"`. I will do some more digging.

Comment: It looks like `idToWorkingObjectMap` only contains entries for `ItemPlanningEntity`; there are no `ReforgeProblemFact` entries. I opened a ticket about this several days ago but didn't get a response, so I posted on SO: [PLANNER-2556](https://issues.redhat.com/projects/PLANNER/issues/PLANNER-2556)

Comment: I revisited the similar SO question and finally got the answer to work. Thanks for your help! I would recommend adding a paragraph in the documentation that answers this error

Answer (score 0):

[Upgrade OptaPlanner](https://www.optaplanner.org/download/upgradeRecipe/), for example to the recently released 8.12.0.Final, to get a helpful error message like this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The externalObject (2018-10-01T10:15-12:15) with planningId ((class org.optaplanner.examples.conferencescheduling.domain.Timeslot, 0)) has no known workingObject (null).
Maybe the workingObject was never added because the planning solution doesn't have a @ProblemFactCollectionProperty annotation on a member with instances of the externalObject's class (class org.optaplanner.examples.conferencescheduling.domain.Timeslot).
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.lookup.PlanningIdLookUpStrategy.lookUpWorkingObject(PlanningIdLookUpStrategy.java:76)
```

That has an error message which has a "Maybe" line that directly points to the solution shown in the other answer.